# How to save object to a mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongodb and I am having challenges saving.

My Schema is

```
const transaction = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: ObjectId,
        default: null,
        transaction_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: transaction_types,
            default: null
        }
    },
    recipient: {
        type: ObjectId,
        default: null,
        transaction_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: transaction_types,
            default: null
        }
    },
    coins: {
        type: Number
    },
    fee: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
}, {
    timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at', deleted_at: 'deleted_at'}
})
```

In my controller, I am doing this

```
await WalletTransaction.create({
                sender: user._id,
                recipient: recipient,
                coins: coins
            });
```

How do I save the transaction type alongside the sender and recipient.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my model to

```
const transaction = new Schema({
    sender: {
        user: {
            type: ObjectId,
            default: null,
        },
        transaction_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: transaction_types,
            default: null
        }
    },
    recipient: {
        user: {
            type: ObjectId,
            default: null,
        },
        transaction_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: transaction_types,
            default: null
        }
    },
    coins: {
        type: Number
    },
    fee: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
}, {
    timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at', deleted_at: 'deleted_at'}
})
```

and on saving, I did this

```
await WalletTransaction.create({
    sender: {
        user: user._id,
        transaction_type: "sent"
    },
    recipient: {
        user: recipient,
        transaction_type: "received"
    },
    coins: coins
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `WalletTransaction` the model of the `transaction` schema? you may do this to save the document:

```js
const t = await WalletTransaction.create({
                sender: user._id,
                recipient: recipient,
                coins: coins
            });
await t.save();
```

Comment: yes, `WalletTransaction` is the model of the `transaction` schema.
My biggest challenge is saving `transaction_type` alongside the sender/recipient

Comment: Just call the `save` method of the document you create, they will be save all in the same document